# Is there a backup tool for linux that allows selective deletion as well as performing backups with just a public key on the client?

Tags: linux, security, backup

In the era of GDPR, making backups comply with all regulations can be a busy task. I am looking for a backup tool for linux that allows me to:

1. Selectively delete files in the backup.
2. Do a backup from a client that only has access to a public key.

[bacula](http://blog.bacula.org/) seems like it could fulfill my requirements, but its documentation is quite verbose. If someone knows that it does fulfill my requirements, that would be of help, too.

Comment: [Duplicati 2](https://www.duplicati.com/) (which can be configured to use GPG which can use public-key crypto) _could_ be an option here but doesn't have a stable release yet nor can it delete old files without access to the decryption key.